# How to call global methods to class from main class in Selenium using TestNG

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, testng

```js
package com.MavenLearning.Login;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LoginOne {
 
 @Test
  public void LoginTestOne() 
 
 {
  {
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Webdriver\\geckodriver.exe");
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.get("http://www.demo.guru99.com/v4/");
   driver.findElement(By.name("uid")).sendKeys("mngr105709");
   driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("jajeten");
   driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();
   assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "Guru99 Bank Manager HomePage");
   String A = driver.getTitle();
   System.out.println(A);
   String B = "Guru99 Bank Manager HomePage";
   System.out.println(B);
   if (A.equals(B))
    System.out.println("Page Title matches");
   else
    System.out.println("Page Title Doesn't Match");
  }
  }
}
```

Seniors, I have written my code in Selenium and stored it in a global method. I don't know how to call the method in the other class. When I was learning Selenium with Java I was easily calling methods to different class but stuck now with TestNG. I have tried importing the method package so everything should work but no success. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Global if you mean `public static` then you just need to call it like below:

```
ClassName.functionName()
```

If it is not static then you need to create an object of that class and then call the function like:

```
MyClass my = new MyClass();
my.MyFunctionName();
```

Updated

You need to create a xml file and specifically all classes which you need to execute.

Example of xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="example suite 1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Regression suite 1" >
    <classes>
      <class name="com.first.example.demoOne"/>
      <class name="com.first.example.demoTwo"/>
      <class name="com.second.example.demoThree"/>
    </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

Source:

http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/testngxml-example-to-execute-with-class-names

Video tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNhnqVWD_54

Comment: Shubham, I created a new TestNG class to call the method but still not sure how to implement it. Sorry I am a fresher with Java. Please see the script below. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: package com.MavenLearning.Login;
import com.MavenLearning.Login.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class CallMethodToLogin {
  @Test
  public void f() {
  }
}

Comment: Thanks Shubham, so in TestNG everything happens from making changes in the xml file?

Comment: Not everything ... The annotations you need to pass in script only and all other features like parallel execution, adding listeners , adding parameters all you can achieve it using XML ... It's java and you can achieve anything which you want by correct implementation ..  ... If my answer help you then Please accept the answer by clicking the right sign just below of vote up and down section .. it will really help .. thanks